# Why does Bootstrap breaks some css code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add bootsrtap the thing which is made using native css doesn't show on the right place for some unknown reason to me.
Here is what [happens with bootstrap](https://puu.sh/xnjju/ad71ced198.png)  and [without](https://puu.sh/xnjvq/947723e176.png). The second shall happen on the first too.
Just a note this thing shall be a population pyramid, sorted by womans(red) and males(blue) by age.

Edit: jsfiddle.net/64mjs03f/

Comment: Please provide a simple set of HTML and CSS code to demonstrate what you're seeing. Images are not helpful when trying to help you figure out why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Examining the HTML and the CSS which produce these examples would be a good first step.  In general, yes, when you add or modify code then behavior may change.

Comment: I added part of the code https://jsfiddle.net/64mjs03f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be due to **Normalization**.

Libraries like bootstrap now come with a Normalized CSS. What that does is, reset the styles of the HTML elements that might render differently across browsers.

All browsers have their own CSS for rendering elements. Normalization helps developers create a web app, that looks same across all browsers.

Comment: This is possible, or it could be that the OP is just including the Bootstrap css after their own, so its overriding their styles. It's impossible to know without the OP showing us their code.

Comment: It doesn't matter in that case. I tried both(bs first and then my style and vice versa). It doesn't make a diffrence. Only removing the bs css file fixes it.

Comment: It won;t matter because if Bootstrap added padding to buttons, and you are not overwriting the padding property of button, it won't matter.

The only thing you can do now is adjust your CSS and uses Bootstrap classes wherever possible.

Comment: After some twerking with inscpect and css(web tools) the problem was box-sizing. I set it to intial and everything is fixed now.

Comment: box-sizing is set by bootstrap only and is preferred. You should use that only.